# Dynamically Adding Images to SlideJS

Tags: jquery

I am using the http://www.slidesjs.com library to create a slideshow for mobile websites. The problem is that the images are fetched from the web service and then added to the  control. When I do that the images appears like this:

[image]

Here is the implementation:

```
<div id="slides">
</div>
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $.get(window._resources["load-gallery"], { productId: productId, siteId: 2, presentation: "Media Gallery,Main Image" }).done(function (data) {

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                var url = "http://someurl.com/" + data[i].MediaDocument.Url;

                var img = $('<img>'); 
                img.attr('src', url);
                img.appendTo('#slides');

            }

        });

    });
```

If I don't feed the slides element dynamically and add it as static images/ hardcoded then it works fine and I can swipe through all the images.

Comment: The image does not really help understanding the problem.

Comment: The img elements are added vertically instead of appearing as a slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a bit of guesswork, because I don't know SlideJS, and your code is missing the initialization of the slider, but let's try…)

As per the SlideJS' home page, you must call the following to initialize the slider.

```
$("#slides").slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 528
});
```

I assume that you do this before you load the images from the server. I also assume that SlideJS doesn't react to updates of the gallery, but only accesses them on initilisation.

So, what you must do is to call the initialization after you've loaded the images:

```
$.get(window._resources["load-gallery"], { productId: productId, siteId: 2, presentation: "Media Gallery,Main Image" }).done(function (data) {

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        // insert images and stuff
    }

    // NOW apply slidejs
    $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
    });
});
```

It might also be that SlideJS has got a callback to update the slider after images have added or removed. In that case, your initialization could stay where it is now, you'd only have to call the update method after you've loaded the images.